# MySQL join tables with prices, rooms and seasons

Tags: mysql, join, pivot-table

I have three tables that users can store seasons, rooms and prices. Table 'seasons' is presented here for better understanding of what I want to achive and it is not going to be used in the query.

Tables are:

```
    table seasons

    |usr_id | season_id | season_name |
    |-------|-----------|-------------|
    |   1   |     1     |     June    |
    |   1   |     2     |     July    |
    |   1   |     3     |    August   |


    table rooms

    |usr_id | room_id |   room_name   |
    |-------|---------|---------------|
    |  1    |    1    |    Studio_1   |
    |  1    |    2    |    Studio_2   |
    |  5    |    3    |  Other studio |


    table prices

    |usr_id | price_id | room_id | season_id | price |
    |-------|----------|---------|-----------|-------|
    |   1   |     1    |    1    |     1     |  10   |
    |   1   |     2    |    2    |     1     |  100  |
    |   1   |     3    |    1    |     2     |  20   |
    |   1   |     4    |    2    |     2     |  200  |
    |   1   |     5    |    1    |     3     |  30   |
    |   1   |     6    |    2    |     3     |  300  |
```

I want to query DB and get the prices, in this example for user_id = 1, for each room per season. What I expect to get is:

```
studio_1 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
---------|----|----|----|

studio_2 | 100 | 200 | 300 |
---------|-----|-----|-----|
```

I have tried to join tables 'rooms' and 'price's but I can not get the correct results. I use the following

```
    SELECT r.room_name, p.price
    FROM rooms AS r
    LEFT JOIN prices AS p ON r.room_id = p.room_id
    WHERE p.usr_id = 1
```

Each user will be able to add 'ulimited' seasons and rooms

Any suggetions?
Thank you

Comment: What's usr_id??

Comment: The id or the user that added rooms, seasons and prices

Comment: I know it's not really relevant, but I'm just trying to think of a scenario in which two different users would provide two different prices for the same room in the same season

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a pivot-table. You can reduce the result to one row per room_id with `GROUP BY` and then use conditional expressions to show only the price per season.

```
SELECT r.room_name, 
    MAX(CASE p.season_id WHEN 1 THEN p.price END) AS price_season_1,
    MAX(CASE p.season_id WHEN 2 THEN p.price END) AS price_season_2,
    MAX(CASE p.season_id WHEN 3 THEN p.price END) AS price_season_3,
    MAX(CASE p.season_id WHEN 4 THEN p.price END) AS price_season_4
FROM rooms AS r
LEFT JOIN prices AS p ON r.room_id = p.room_id
WHERE p.usr_id = $usr_id
GROUP BY r.room_id
```

When writing pivot-table queries, you must hard-code each column and write an expression for each corresponding value.

---

Re your comment:

> the number of seasons is not the same for each user, as each user will be able to create as many as seasons he needs.

Then you need to do a preceding query so your application can discover the seasons needed for the given user.

```
SELECT season_id, season_name FROM seasons where usr_id = 1
```

Then use this data to form as many columns in the select-list as needed for that user. Do this with application code.

If you read about pivot-tables, you'll find that this is always necessary. You must know the columns before you can write the query. SQL cannot add more columns while it's executing, based on the data values it finds.

Comment: the problem is that the number of seasons is not the same for each user, as each user will be able to create as many as seasons he needs.